# reading all the images in a directory and saving as (.mat file matrixes) into another directory

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, scikit-image, imread

I'm working with kinect, and just started with python.

I know how to read an image and save as a matrix in python.

But how can I manage to read all images in a directory and save as matrix files (.mat files) in another directory?

Could you give a brief short example?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using scikit-image, you can utilise the ImageCollection object:

```
from skimage import io
images = io.imread_collection('/path/to/images/*.jpg')

for (image, fn) in zip(images, images.files):
    np.savetxt(fn + '.txt', image)
```

Comment: But why it doesn't work? It doesn't give a syntax error, but also it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the result of ``len(images)``?

Comment: Actually it was the problem of importing. But I still couldn't have time to try your approach.

Comment: importing problem that u have to download scikit-image first, if you working on pycharm  ( File  -> Settings -> project interpreter ) then chose library and it will work

Answer (score 2):

What is a matrix file ? Is it binary, or ascii ? I assume you have a function for saving and loading. Call this function `img2mat`, and assume it takes an input img file name and an output matrix file name. Below I am using the `os` module, which is a tool for interacting with the operating system. I would do something like

```
import os

import scipy.io as sio
import scipy

def img2mat( infile , outfile, matlab_name):
    arr = scipy.misc.imread(infile) # should already be loaded as a np.array
    sio.savemat(outfile, { matlab_name: arr})

dirpath = '/path/to/images'

img_ext = '.jpg' #for example
img_fnames = [ os.path.join(dirpath,x) for x in os.listdir( dirpath ) if x.endswith(img_ext) ] 

outpath = '/path/to/outputfolder'

mat_fnames = [ os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0] +'.mat' for x in img_fnames ] 
mat_fnames = [ os.path.join( outpath, x ) for x in mat_fnames ] 

for i,(in,out) in enumerate( zip( img_fnames, mat_fnames) ):
    img2mat( in,out, 'img%d'%i)
```

Assuming you don't have too many images, I would save multiple images to the same file.

```
img_dict = { 'img%d'%i: scipy.misc.imread(fname) for i,fname in enumerate( img_fnames) }

sio.savemat( 'allimg.mat', img_dict )
```

Comment: Thanks Dermen, I'm gonna try right now and let you know about it.

Comment: Actually, if you want to save one image file as 1 matrix, the code will be like this: arr = imread('/path/to/image') arr = np.array(arr) sio.savemat ('R.mat', {R : arr}) I'm sorry I'm new in python, so in this case how can we implement it?

Comment: so then you will use this file in matlab ? In which case, after you load the R.mat file you will obtain the R object (in matlab) which is the image?

Comment: Actually I won't use it in matlab. But sometimes I need to check the matrix file. I use Matlab for this issue. And I also know how to load the '.mat' files back.

Comment: I added a little bit of code. Any reason why you want one file per img ? It seems you can save imgs in the same file

Comment: Thank you dermen, but I actually need one mat file for each image.

Comment: sounds good, btw, not sure who downvoted you, but I would suggest you elaborate on what you mean by ```matrix``` or ```.mat``` file. In python there is a ```matrix``` object which is similar to a ```np.array```. It seems you are actually saving the images as ```np.arrays```.